# Angular 4 how can i do trigger change like jquery trigger('change')

Tags: angular, trigger.io

I am trying to trigger change in angular 4 for input field after put value in it by `this.my_var = my_val`, and then how can I trigger change event?

**Code-**

```js
import { Component, OnInit,OnDestroy, Renderer, ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
 @ViewChild('mka_gb') mka_gb:ElementRef;
 
 constructor(private router: Router, private renderer:Renderer) {  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getOverviewData(); 
    let search = window.localStorage.getItem('search_val');
    window.localStorage.setItem('search_val', '');
    console.log(search);
    if(search != '') {
      setTimeout(()=>{
        this.mka_search = search;
        let event = new MouseEvent('click', {bubbles: true});
        this.renderer.invokeElementMethod(
        this.mka_gb.nativeElement, 'dispatchEvent', [event]);
      },300);
      
    }
  }
```

```html
<input #mka_gb type="text" pInputText size="50" placeholder="Global Filter" class="form-control" [ngModel]="mka_search">
```

Comment: can you add more information. Visit [**asking help**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before asking :)

Comment: what you tried any code samples

Comment: also angular has nice documentation go and read it https://angular.io/guide/user-input

Comment: Thanks to reply, I always use jQuery, This is first time i am working with Angular, i just want to know how to manually trigger any event in angular as we do in jQuery like : trigger('change'), trigger('click') etc.

Comment: you have compile errors? your code seems correct.

Comment: are you aking about `(ngModelChange)` or `(input)` events?. In Angular the idea is adding in the .html -not add an event in .ts- (or creating a directive with hostBinding) only in a few and rare ocassions we manipulate the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ViewChild:

```
import { Component, Renderer, ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  ...
  template: `
...
<input #fileInput type="file" id="imgFile" (click)="onChange($event)" >
...`
})
class MyComponent {
  @ViewChild('fileInput') fileInput:ElementRef;

  constructor(private renderer:Renderer) {}

  exampleFunctionWhenYouWantToFireEvent() {
    let event = new MouseEvent('click', {bubbles: true});
    this.renderer.invokeElementMethod(
        this.fileInput.nativeElement, 'dispatchEvent', [event]);
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried this, it gives a error "ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined" , What may i am doing wrong..?

Comment: you add #fileInput sintaxis to control you want to trigger event? show me your code then i can help you.

Comment: My Input Field is : <input #mka_gb type="text" pInputText size="50" placeholder="Global Filter" class="form-control" id="search-field" [ngModel]="mka_search">

Comment: @ViewChild('mka_gb') mka_gb:ElementRef;

ngOnInit() {
    this.getOverviewData(); 
    let search = window.localStorage.getItem('search_val');
    window.localStorage.setItem('search_val', '');
    console.log(search);
    if(search != '') {
      setTimeout(()=>{
        this.mka_search = search;
        let event = new MouseEvent('click', {bubbles: true});
        this.renderer.invokeElementMethod(
        this.mka_gb.nativeElement, 'dispatchEvent', [event]);
      },300);
      
    }
  }

Comment: man, if you want I can help you, pls, add all of your coded, view and controller formatted on your first post.